# Creating a user profile form in Django 1.2

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying create a basic form which will allow the user to update their firstname, lastname and email as part of the User model. I've tried the following code:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class BasicAccountForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')
```

It's throwing the following error:

```
Caught AttributeError while rendering: 'User' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong, or if there is a better way to do what I am trying to accomplish?

Comment: Check if, you have something like `user.get` in your template. Exception points into that direction.

Answer (score 3):

Figured this out, if anyone has the same problem, please see this link: http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/BackwardsIncompatibleChanges#ModelFormsconstructornowmatchesForms